# what does this expression do ? default=lambda self: _('New'))

Tags: python, orm, odoo

I am working on Odoo Erp and during code analysis i found this expression in a field definition

```
default=lambda self: _('New')
```

the exact expression is:

```
reference = fields.Char(string='Schedule Reference', required=True, copy=False, readonly=True, states={'draft': [('readonly', False)]}, index=True, default=lambda self: _('New'))
```

i want to know what is _('New') do here.

Comment: That will depend on what `_` is defined as.

Answer (score 3):

The field default value will be used to create new records and it accepts a direct value or a function to be called. Using a function is a way to be able to use the context values like lang of the current user in order to be able to return more accurate values.

The _ function in Odoo is the translation shortcut function so _('New') is a way to return the translation of the 'New' string and due to the _ function is used with the current user context is able to return the translation of the value for the user defined lang if it's available.

Answer (score 0):

We will get a default value as 'New' for the field, do not worry about _ it is for translation only, if you did not have _ than translation will not work.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).